# Do i need to exclude id, that are like about 70% of records in table from complex index

Tags: indexing, psql

I hava a simple test table

id iteger pk,
test_id integer fk ....,
someFlag boolean,
other columns....

most of time we need to get a row by test_id and someFlag, so that i made an index

`create index test_index(test_id, someFlag)` - and everything going good, but 70% of records in this table have same test_id and if i trying to get rows with it - there is no index scan, seq scan only.
So if this test_id do not scan by index should i exlude it from my index like this

```
create index test_index(test_id, someFlag) where test_id != some value;
```

it will make the index size much smaller and index scan will be faster

Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the Postgres docs on [Partial Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html):

> One major reason for using a partial index is to avoid indexing common values. Since a query searching for a common value (one that accounts for more than a few percent of all the table rows) will not use the index anyway, there is no point in keeping those rows in the index at all. This reduces the size of the index, which will speed up those queries that do use the index.